# ¿Por qué no me funciona el "switch - case"?

Tags: c, punteros, switch, estructuras, union

El siguiente código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct survey_information {
    char name[50];
    union { char street[50];
            char district[50];
    }strdis;
    enum str_or_dis {si = 0, no = 1} type;
};

typedef struct survey_information survey;

void data_enter (survey *ptr_survey) {

    strcpy (ptr_survey -> name, "Efrain Mayor Amaro");
    ptr_survey -> type = si;
    strcpy (ptr_survey -> strdis.street, "Calle de Leganes");
    strcpy (ptr_survey -> strdis.district, "Distrito de Madrid");
}

void data_display(survey *ptr_survey) {
    printf("\n %s \n", ptr_survey->name);
    switch (ptr_survey->type)
    {
    case 0:
        printf("\n %s \n", ptr_survey->strdis.street);
        break;
    case 1:
        printf("\n %s \n",ptr_survey->strdis.district);
        break;    
    default:
        break;
    }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    survey var1;
    survey *ptr_survey= &var1;
    data_enter(ptr_survey);
    data_display(ptr_survey);
    return 0;
}
```

, debería mostrar por pantalla:

```
Efrain Mayor Amaro

Calle de Leganés

Pero en cambio muestra:

Efrain Mayor Amaro

Distrito de Madrid
```

He intentado asignar 0 directamente (en vez de "si") al `campo type` de la estructura `var1`, eliminar el case 1 y poner: `printf("\n %s \n",ptr_survey->strdis.district); break;` en `default` pero siempre muestra el mismo resultado excepto si no asigno valor a `strdis.district.`

Me llama la atención que si imprimo el valor del campo type de la `var1`, se imprime un `0` por lo que, en consecuencia, deberían ejecutarse las instrucciones que aparecen en el `case 0` pero contradictoriamente lo que se ejecuta es lo que aparece en el `case 1`.

¿Alguien me puede decir donde está el error y por qué el `switch case` "no funciona"?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El switch sí funciona. El problema es en parte por la estructura y está función:

```
void data_enter (survey *ptr_survey) {
    strcpy (ptr_survey -> name, "Efrain Mayor Amaro");
    ptr_survey -> type = si;
    strcpy (ptr_survey -> strdis.street, "Calle de Leganes");
    strcpy (ptr_survey -> strdis.district, "Distrito de Madrid");
}
```

`strdis` es una [unión](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/union). Lo que sucede es que los campos de las uniones comparten memoria, siendo el tamaño de una unión el mayor de sus campos.

`street` y `district` efectivamente están en la misma memoria, por lo tanto, al escribir uno se sobreescribe el otro. Para que quede claro, supon que tienes la siguiente unión:

```
union {
    int numero;
    char texto[4];
};
```

Y en memoria tienes los bytes **41**, **4C**, **4F**, **48**. Si lees `numero` obtendrás **1095520072** en un sistema de 32 bits little endian. Si lees `texto` verás la palabra **Hola**.

---

Si necesitas que ambos campos existan por separado, considera usar un [`struct`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct):

```
struct { char street[50];
    char district[50];
}strdis;
```

Comment: Eso quiere decir que a una unión sólo se le puede (o debe?) asignar valor en uno de sus campos a la vez y por tanto no debí haber asignado valores a sus dos campos porque en realidad estaba reescribiendo en el mismo espacio de memoria?

Comment: @YalAl exacto. Si asignas valores a varios campos, estás *pisando* los valores que diste a los demás. Por lo tanto, el único campo que deberías leer es el último que asignaste, a menos que tu intención sea hacer [type punning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44137442).